# SQL Server "<>" operator is very slow compared to "=" on table with a few million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have two tables. Forms has ~77000 rows. Logs has ~2.7 million rows.

The following query returns "30198" in less than a second:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logs.DOCID) FROM logs, forms WHERE logs.DOCID = forms.DOCID;
```

And this query has been running for ~15 minutes so far, and still hasn't finished:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logs.DOCID) FROM logs, forms WHERE logs.DOCID <> forms.DOCID;
```

Why is the "not equal" query **so** much slower?

Comment: What about `WHERE NOT logs.DOCID = forms.DOCID`?

Comment: Are you trying to find `logs.DOCID` values for which no corresponding value exists in `forms`? If so try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DOCID FROM logs EXCEPT SELECT DOCID FROM forms ) T`

Comment: @Martin - your query returned in 8 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `=` reduces the join operation to one single matching row from each table (presuming those docids are unique).

Think of it this way- you've got a dance with 5 boys and 5 girls:

```
Adam      Alice
Bob       Betty
Charly    Cathy
Dick      Deb
Evan      Elly
```

You pair them up by first letter. So

```
Adam->Alice
Bob->Betty
etc...
```

One single pairing

But if you pair them up by "First letters do NOT match", you end up with:

```
Adam->Betty
Adam->Cathy
Adam->Deb
Adam->Elly
Bob->Alice
etc...
```

you've MASSIVELY increased the number of pairings. This is why your `<>` query is taking so long. You're essentially trying to fetch `m x n` rows, rather than just `min(m,n)`. With this data, you end up with 25 rows, rather than 5. For your specified table sizes, you're working with 77,000 * 2,700,000 = 207.9 billion rows, minus 77,000 where the two ids match up, for a total of 207,899,923,000 rows in the joined data set.

---

given your query requirements, try a left join and look for null right-side records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT logs.DOCID
FROM logs
LEFT JOIN forms ON logs.DOCID = forms.DOCID
WHERE forms.DOCID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 I'm guessing the OP probably needs `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT`

Comment: Thanks! Nothing I can do to optimize my query? I'm looking for any formIDs in the logs table that don't correspond to formIDs in the forms table. I think I know the answer by finding the delta of COUNT(DISTINCT logs.formID), and COUNT(DISTINCT logs.formID) WHERE logs.formID = forms.formID

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DOCID FROM logs EXCEPT SELECT DOCID FROM forms ) T`

Comment: @Marc - RE: Your edit. This is the least efficient way of doing an anti semi join in SQL Server. [link 1](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/), [link 2](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: @Martin Smith - With DISTINCT or a GROUP BY on the two inner queries (The OP has `COUNT(DISTINCT)` so I'm guessing these are not unique fields...)

Comment: Thanks all. This helps me understand SQL a bit better.



`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logs.DOCID) FROM logs, formId WHERE logs.DOCID NOT IN (SELECT forms.DOCID FROM forms);` returned in 11 seconds.



@Martin Smith - 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DOCID FROM logs EXCEPT SELECT DOCID FROM forms) T;` returned in 8 seconds.

Comment: @Dems - `EXCEPT` removes duplicates

Comment: @TRedman a suggestion, even though you will likely go with Martin's `EXCEPT` suggestion - don't use `NOT IN` unless you are absolutely 100% certain the column on the inside cannot be `NULL`.  `NOT EXISTS` is usually preferable over `NOT IN`.

Comment: @TRedman - I'd ***strongly*** recommend that you stop using the `,` notation.  The code in your comment above is doing this...  *Take the `logs` table, exclude every record where it's `DOCID` isn't in the `forms` table, then join every remaining record against the entirety of the `forms` table. (77000 matches per record, a cross product, and I'm sure you didn't mean it)*

Comment: @Dems I will have to get used to this... `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.DOCID) FROM logs l INNER JOIN forms f ON f.DOCID = l.DOCID;`

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons:

- queries for equivalence can generally use indexes (if available), while query for nonequivalence cannot
- `<>` returns so much more data.

Your query with `<>` is bogus. What should it return?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It should return ~3800. I'm looking for any formIDs in the logs table that don't correspond to formIDs in the forms table. Somebody else has answered above - I should be using `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: Yes. Another possibility would be `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` with `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally dependant on the distribution of values in the table. If the column you are searching, for example had the same value `(= forms.DOCID)` for 99.99 % of the rows and only one row with a different value, you would see exactly the opposite behavior.