# Is it better to use equal or not equal when making a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I'm working with a MySQL database but this question could apply to SQL, Oracle, etc.

I have a table with products and one of the columns is the brand, I give the user the possibility of selecting which brands he wants. And here comes my question, is it better to make a query selecting all results from that table that match the selected brands or to make a query selecting all results from that table that don't match the unselected brands?

Thus,

> is it more efficient/faster (or the same) to look for results equal to something or
>   not equal? and why...

Comment: Have you tried running any tests to determine the timings?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419251/sql-server-operator-is-very-slow-compared-to-on-table-with-a-few-millio.  My understanding was always equals has better performance than not equals due to the better use of indexing.  But you usually don't see a problem like the person is experiencing in that question often where it's 1 second > 15+ minutes.

Comment: Yep, I've just seen that question and it does not seem normal, it could help though

Comment: @takendarkk yes I've run some tests but my table is not big enough yet so I can't really test it. I'm trying to make the correct decisions to be prepared for when the table grows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance is one reason to use `=`.  There are two components to this.  First is indexing, where `=` comparisons provide for more powerful indexing capabilities.  The second is partitioning.  Although unlikely on a column that takes just a handful of values, `=` is better for resolving partitions.

Another reason is semantic.  The presence of `NULL`s can be confusing.  Consider the two comparisons:

```
where col = 'x'
where col <> 'x'
```

Both of these `where` clauses filter out values where `col` is `NULL`.  This makes total sense with the `=`.  However, even after you know the rules, it is a bit confusing with the `<>`.  Intuitively, we think "`NULL` is not equal to "x", so it should be true".  In fact, `NULL` means an unknown value, and an unknown value *could* be equal to `'x'`, so the statement *could* be true; in fact, it returns `NULL` which is filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance point of view you would want to use equals to make use of indexing.

From a logical point of view it would be dangerous to use 'not equals'.  In this scenario you could delete unexpected data.
1. Retrieve a list of brands
2. Present the list to the user
3. Another action inserts a new brand X
4. User chooses which brands to keep and presses delete.
5. Brand x has been unintentionally deleted.